# How to copy text content from a node list into a new list

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I am trying to figure out how to copy the text content from my nodeList into a new navigation bar for my mobile version.

The original navigation bar was created in HTML. I turned my **ul** into a nodeList and then I created all the new elements **li**, **a**, and **href** and appended them to where they need to go, but I can't figure out how to copy the text content from my original list and display it into my new one. The closest I got was this example, and it makes sense why it is displaying all text in each anchor but I can't figure out how to get it right. I also left out the HTML main content because it does not pertain.

```
</head>

<body>
<div class="smallMenuLink"><a href="#smallNavArea">MENU</a></div>


<nav>
<ul id="primaryNavigation">
<li><a id="indexFile" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
<li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="keepOpen"></div>
</nav>

<nav id="smallNavArea"></nav>
<footer>
<p>Andrew Kester</p>
</footer>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
function duplicateMenu() {
    // get all of the anchor elements from the top menu
    let topList = document.querySelectorAll('ul#primaryNavigation li a') //This creates the NodeList 
    
    // create the new list items for the bottom of the page
    let newList = document.createElement('ul') // -------------------------creates a new ul

    topList.forEach(menuItem => { //---------------------------------------Loops through all elements in nodelist
        let newListItem = document.createElement('li')
        let newLink = document.createElement('a') //-----------------------creates an anchor
        newLink.setAttribute('href', menuItem.getAttribute('href')) // ----this extracts the href from each anchor and Adds href to the Anchor

        // 'copy' or 'modify' the textContent from upper menu to new menu
        newLink.textContent = primaryNavigation.textContent

        // append children to make them appear in the DOM
        newListItem.append(newLink)
        newList.append(newListItem)
        document.querySelector('#smallNavArea').append(newList)
         /* console.log(newList)  */

    })
}

duplicateMenu()
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is copy the ul's inner html (list items and anchors), use the `innerHTML` of the original `ul` and place that inside the new `ul`,  this is much simpler than doing it the way you are doing it.

**EDIT:** Removed all `id` attributes of the list items and anchors of the new `ul`

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   const navarea = document.querySelector('#smallNavArea');
   const primeul = document.querySelector('#primaryNavigation');
   const newul = document.createElement('ul');
   //set the new ul elements innerHTML to the primary's innerHTML
   newul.innerHTML = primeul.innerHTML;
   //append the new ul element
   navarea.appendChild(newul);
   //remove id attributes, so they remain unique
   navarea.querySelectorAll('li,a').forEach((el) => {
       el.removeAttribute('id');
   });
});
```

```html
<nav>
<ul id="primaryNavigation">
<li><a id="indexFile" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
<li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="keepOpen"></div>
</nav>

<nav id="smallNavArea"></nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have to use the [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method and be careful to [remove all the `ID`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) to not duplicate them

```js
function duplicateMenu()
  {
  const
    topList  = document.querySelector('ul#primaryNavigation')
  , smallNav = document.querySelector('#smallNavArea')
  , newList  = topList.cloneNode(true)
    ;

  // remove All ID:
  newList.removeAttribute('id');   
  newList.querySelectorAll('[id]').forEach( el => el.removeAttribute('id') );

  smallNav.appendChild(newList);
  }
duplicateMenu();
```

```html
<div class="smallMenuLink"><a href="#smallNavArea">MENU</a></div>

<nav>
  <ul id="primaryNavigation">
    <li><a id="indexFile" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="keepOpen"></div>
</nav>

<nav id="smallNavArea"></nav>
<footer>
  <p>Andrew Kester</p>
</footer>
```